# Качество изображения ухудшается ("мылится") при старте формы

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

В проекте c# windows form, в конструкторе изображение PNG отображается с отличным качеством, но после запуска качество очень сильно ухудшается ("мылится"), как это можно исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в конструкторе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

во время запуска

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какая версия .NET используется? Использование ico не спасает ситуацию?

Comment: Убедитесь, что свойство [AutoScaleDimensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscaledimensions?view=net-5.0) установлено в правильное значение: `this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);`. Также можете попробовать включить [High DPI support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)